# Merge with dual not working in 12c

Tags: oracle, merge

Hi I am using Oracle 12c and I have executed the below query which returns 0 rows merged. Please advise if I am doing something wrong.

The table `cons_temp` contains two columns, 
`name`, `value`.

```
 merge into cons_temp tb
 using (select 'Freez' as NAME, 'NOI' as VALUE from dual where 1=2) v
 on (tb.NAME=v.NAME)
 when matched then update set tb.VALUE=v.VALUE
 when not matched then insert (NAME,VALUE) values(v.NAME, v.VALUE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why have you put this line in the USING query?

```
where 1=2
```

That will always evaluate to false (because 1 != 2). Consequently your USING query will return zero rows, so there is nothing to match or unmatch.

If you remove that WHERE clause your statement will do something.